# Any large USB sticks with integrated card readers?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, sd-card, card-reader

I have one of [Kingston's DataTraveller Micro Reader USB sticks](http://www.ubergizmo.com/15/archives/2008/02/kingston_datatraveler_micro_reader.html), a fantastic memory stick with an integrated micro SD and M2 card reader.  However, I've gradually filled it to the brim and am looking for a larger stick.  Unfortunately, Kingston don't make them any bigger than the 4GB one that I currently have and I was hoping to go to 16GB now that they've come down in price.

Does anyone know if any manufacturers make something similar: a 16GB stick with a micro SD card reader integrated (I'm not bothered about the M2 reader).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an 8GB Micro SD, and SD to USB converter / reader:

http://www.eforcity.com/257519.html?efprcggbadtf090605=257519

I wasnt able to find any 16GB models.

Im not exacally sure what you are looking for. Do you want a 16 GB USB memory stick that can also read Micro SD and SD at the same time?

If you just need an adapter, this may also work too:

[http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820134988](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820134988&nm_mc=OTC-Froogle&cm_mmc=OTC-Froogle-_-Memory+(Flash+Memory)-_-Kingston+Technology+Corp.-_-20134988)

Comment: Thanks for the 8GB one: that's the kind of thing I was looking for: a 16GB USB memory stick that can also read micro SD (I don't need SD).

Comment: How about this: http://www.geekstuff4u.com/buffalo-microsd-usb-card-reader-16gb.html?___store=en

You may have to order it from japan though, or search for a differnt seller.

Comment: Thanks, but the buffalo one is just a micro-sd card reader and doesn't have any built-in memory.